# Como gerar um pdf com Primefaces 5.3 usando dataexport

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsp, relatório

Esta e minha tela para gerar o pdf

```
<p:panel style="margin-left:30%" id="pnlTituloGabarito">
        <p:commandButton value="Export to PDF" ajax="false">
        <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="subTableRespostas" fileName="gabaritoPDF"/>
        </p:commandButton>
        <h:outputLabel value="Instituição: "/>
        <h:outputText value="#{GabaritoRespostaControl.prova.instituicao.nomeFantasia}"/>
        <h:outputLabel style="margin-left:2.5%" value="Turma / Período: "/>
        <h:outputText value=" #{GabaritoRespostaControl.prova.periodo}"/>
        <a:newLine/>
        <h:outputLabel value="Curso: "/>
        <h:outputText value=" #{GabaritoRespostaControl.prova.curso.nome}"/>
        <h:outputLabel style="margin-left:1.5%" value="Disciplina: "/>
        <h:outputText value="#{GabaritoRespostaControl.prova.disciplina.nome}"/>
    </p:panel>
    <p:dataTable  var="listaPaginada" id="dTblRespostas" emptyMessage="Não há nenhuma questão para esta prova!" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="440" style="width:30%; margin-left:30%" value="#{GabaritoRespostaControl.gabarito.dataTableDividido }">
        <p:subTable id="subTableRespostas" value="#{listaPaginada }"  var="questao">
            <p:column headerText="Questão">
                <h:outputText value="#{questao.key }"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Resposta">
                <h:outputText value="#{questao.value }"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:subTable>
    </p:dataTable>

</p:panel>
```

Gera o seguinte erro quando clico no botao:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component for expression "subTableRespostas" referenced from "formCorpo:j_idt92".
>       javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
>       org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: Estou usando os mesmos exemplos do showcase do primeface 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caro colega,

Olhando a documentação do Primefaces, essa dataExport não possui um subTable dentro de um dataTable. Provavelmente a implementação que cria o PDF não consegue pegar os dados por esse componente. Tenta tirar o subTable e só deixar o dataTable.